# Loyalty Management Implementation

Tags: administration, admin

I need to implement Loyalty Management in my sandbox org, I checked the trailhead and it talks about a permission set, but there isn't. I checked the documentation and it says that I should find it in the app launcher, but there isn't. Does anybody can tell me how to implement it in my org ?
Thank you :D

Comment: You need a license for Loyalty Management product, permission set will not show up without it.

Comment: Thank you so much